# Query succeeds in phpmyadmin and in fails in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Can anyone tell me a reason a query just wont return the same data in php as the ones that it returns on phpmyadmin sql?

```
$query = "UPDATE `boards` SET `contestPlaces`=0, `contestPlacesFilled`=0";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR:QUERY_FAILED timeset 8" . mysql_error()); 

$query = "UPDATE `playerspoints` SET `points`=0";   
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR:QUERY_FAILED timeset 9" . mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT `avatarId`, `points` FROM `contestants`"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR:QUERY_FAILED timeset 10" . mysql_error());

$qualified = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result));
{
    print_r($row);
    $qualified[] = $row;
} `
```

Result: Array ( [0] => ) SUCCESS.

I get no error, it just returns an empty result, while in phpmyadmin sql tab, it runs fine. 
I'm properly connected with the db, cause I run queries before this one. I checked to see and this one is the only one that fails without an apparent reason. So What should I look in order to see what's going wrong?

The user that I get connected to the database has the following privileges:
`SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, EVENT, TRIGGER, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EXECUTE`

Comment: And how do you know the result is empty?

Comment: Because I do a print_r after i fetch the first row. I'll edit the code and add that as well.

Comment: Did you checked connection data? is it correct?

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I run other queries before this one and they work. There is a contestants table, I request for valid fields, this just doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: do you connect as same user in phpmyadmin as this query does?

Comment: O_O no. But the user that I get connected with has all privileges for that database. Any suggestions on what to look? I hope that's the problem because its driving me crazy.

Comment: are you sure you have all permissions granted that are necessary for this user?  try granting them for this user and flushing privileges

Comment: I listed the privileges in the question.

Comment: login as user and attempt query.

Comment: this may not help but, are you sure `contestants` is not empty?

Comment: Are you connected to the right db?

Comment: yes, all previous queries are depended on the same db. And I'm sure contestants is not empty.

Comment: can you post the query above this one that is working properly?

Comment: can you extract record from  `playerspoints` and `boards` table? if they will also return `Result: Array ( [0] => ) SUCCESS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the semicolon:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result));
                                      ^
```

Comment: You have no Idea how happy you made me, sneaky semi colon... THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!
And thanks to everyone else who tried to help. You guys rock.

Answer (score -1):

//this is latest code in php5.7.14  and accesses the database.....but still it was not working.
//therefore, i found that the database coallition was not 'utf_general_ci' rather i kept default leading to 'latin_swedish'.
//single mistake can ruin your project.

```
<?php
$mysqli_hostname = "localhost";
$mysqli_user = "root";
$mysqli_password = "krunal";
$mysqli_database = "krunal";
$bd = mysqli_connect($mysqli_hostname, $mysqli_user,  $mysqli_password,$mysqli_database);  
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){die("database connection  failed");}
?>


<?php 
 $sql= "SELECT * FROM `done`;";
$result=mysqli_query($bd,$sql);
if(!$result){
die("database query failed". mysqli_connect_error()."    (".mysqli_connect_errno().")");}?>



<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
var_dump($row); }?>

<?php mysqli_close($bd);?>
```

Comment: This is a question or what? It has nothing to do with the original post.